# Can't add selector with options to DOM with fetching api

Tags: javascript, dom, fetch-api

this is my first question here, so I'm little bit nervous ;)
My problem is, how to add selector with options to DOM. Main question is that I have api to  get data and the value of options should be added from this api. At the beginning I create button to start the function, but then code doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
const btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.setAttribute("id", "getCurrencies");
btn.innerHTML = "Click me!";
document.body.appendChild(btn);

btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  fetch("https://api.frankfurter.app/latest")
    .then((response) => response.json)
    .then((data) => {
      const selectEL = createElement("select");
      const currencies = Object.entries(data.rates).forEach(([code, value]) => {
        const optionEl = createElement("option");
        // optionEl.setAttribute("value", code);
        optionEl.innerHTML = ($[code], $[value]);
        selectEL.appendChild(optionEl);
      });
      document.body.appendChild(selectEL);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple mistakes. Start debugging your code piece by piece.
If you first look at the console you will get error "ReferenceError: createElement is not defined"

1. createElement calls for select and option are not going to work, you are missing WHERE in the document to create them. document.createElement works like in the first line of code.

Then you fix those and get the next error "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

2. You are not calling response.json(). It doesn't do the conversion without calling the function. So it will give typeError.

Then you fix the json call. You will now get error "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" This means $ is not defined and the transpiler has no idea what to do. By looking at your code:

3. Your innerHTML set is wrong. You could use es6 string `optionEl.innerHTML =` ${code} - ${value}`;`

Now it starts to work.

4. I would split the code to functions so it is easier to read.

So start by debugging from the beginning. Remove code lines and read what the console prints for you.

See working example without code splitting: https://codepen.io/shnigi/pen/NWvNwXQ

Comment: Thanks for help :) Now it's working properly. I made some mistakes and I didn't notice them. One thing more, I have to catch code and value by ` mark.

Comment: If you mean the innerHTML set yes you have to use backticks ` to use it as a es6 string. Explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals To put you code inside try catch block read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch If you found my answer helpful please give me upvote =)

Answer (score -2):

You should do it like this:

```
$(document).on('click','#getCurrencies',function(){
 // ...
});
```

This binds a click event to the document and all child elements within it. This method is referred to as delegated event handling.

Comment: This doesn't fix anything as the code is bad and contains multiple errors.

Comment: Also, there is no indication that jQuery is being used, or is available. So why suggest using jQuery and offering no explanation for your code to show what it does, or offer any insight into the library you're suggesting?